# Yeoman project aborting due to not finding compass

Tags: npm, sass, yeoman, compass, yeoman-generator

Following a tutorial from "JavaScript Frameworks for Modern Web Development" (ch. 3 on Yeoman) to setup Yeoman and scaffold a simple project:

Working in git-bash, I installed the Yeoman generator "modernweb" (cmd: npm install -g generator-modernweb) and successfully scaffolded my project (cmd: yo modernweb). When I run the grunt command to build and launch, I get the following error:
[Warning: not found: compass  Use --force to continue  Aborted due to warnings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4OZtM.png)

I can find the compass module in my node_modules folder and, if I look inside Gruntfile.js, I can see where grunt-contrib-compass is loaded and configured. So why is grunt not able to find Compass?

After some research I learned that Compass is a Ruby gem so I downloaded Ruby and installed SASS and Compass. Still unable to get this to work however.
I'm running version 3.10.6 of npm and 6.0.0 of node.

Github repo: https://github.com/ahvar/market-maps.git

I would greatly appreciate any help or advice.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please ensure that the path the gems were installed is in your `PATH`.

For example, on Ubuntu: `export PATH=$PATH:/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin` (note that this exact command might not work depending on the OS and the ruby version you're using)

Comment: Thanks! I reinstalled Ruby and checked the box for adding gems to my PATH. I then reinstalled the compass gem and my grunt tasks ran successfully.